# How to get only one countour for each shape that is detected using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

```
I am trying to extract the rectangles in an image after extraction, getting two contours for each shape that is detected i.e, lower bound and upper bound  of each shape. But i need only one countour for shape

I tried to convert the image to binary and applied dilation to it and extracted each contour. Here iam getting two countours for each shape but i need only one contour for each shape, how can i get only one countour for one shape.

img =  cv2.imread("target2.jpg",0) 
img = cv2.resize(img,(1280,720)) # resizing image as it is large in size
_,thr1 = cv2.threshold(img,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # convering to binary
kernal = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)  #creating small size kernel
dilation = cv2.dilate(thr1, kernal , iterations=1)  # dialating the small pixels in image
contours, hireracy = cv2.findContours(dilation,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  # finding the countours in image
count =0  #conting the rectangles
for i,contour in enumerate(contours):
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True);   #using approxpoly to define the arc thickness
    if len(approx) ==4: # is the poly contains four vertices then its an rectangle
        X,Y,W,H = cv2.boundingRect(approx)      
        aspectratio = float(W)/H
        if aspectratio >=1.5 :
            count = count +1
            cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0,255,0),5)
            x = approx.ravel()[0]
            y = approx.ravel()[1]
            cv2.putText(img, "rectangle"+str(i),(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,0))
print(count)
cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I am trying to extract the rectangles in an image after extraction, getting two contours for each shape that is detected i.e, lower bound and upper bound  of each shape

I tried to convert the image to binary and applied dilation to it and extracted each contour. Here iam getting two countours for each shape but i need only one contour for each shape, how can i get only one countour for one shape.
```

I am trying to extract the rectangles in an image after extraction, getting two contours for each shape that is detected i.e, lower bound and upper bound  of each shape

```
I tried to convert the image to binary and applied dilation to it and extracted each contour. Here iam getting two countours for each shape but i need only one contour for each shape, how can i get only one countour for one shape.
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your image, but try using `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` rather than `cv2.RETR_TREE`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you explain me some internal working of it.

Comment: The EXTERNAL option just gets the outer edges of counters and ignores any ones wholly contained inside, whereas the TREE option gives you the full hierarchical tree of what is on top of what and all the various layers.